# InstallShield Run setup and install prerequisites without asking

Tags: frameworks, installshield, prerequisites

I have a WinForm Application done in Visual Studio 2012, Framework 4.5. I made the Setup Project with InstallShield. I need to install this App on PC that may not have Framework 4.5 installed, so I add Framework 4.5 as a PreRequisite. So far So good. 
What I want is to Install the PreRequisite automatically, without asking my clients when they Runs the Setup. 
Is that Possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Edit your PRQ to always install .net45 with no input. Here is a .net40 PRQ we use locally.

[image]

/passive has it show a progress bar, but you could just as easily do /q (no UI at all). The only problem would be a very long startup delay to your install which the user would probably interpret as "something is wrong" so I'd recommend keeping /passive.

Comment: Add to this: the user will have to run the setup.exe in order to get this behavior; just having them run the msi itself wouldn't call the PRQ. Though if you build a "single file" type setup, that would be a non-issue.

Answer (score 0):

InstallShield doesn't support this feature.  The closest is to make the prerequisite mandatory. Another possibility would be to associate the PRQ to a feature to make it a "feature prereq" instead of a "setup prereq".   This would cause Setup.exe to go right into your MSI and then defer the installation until after user interview.

Comment: Couldn't you make the PRQ for .net45 a hidden one, and pass "/q /norestart" in the PRQ? Then it would be installed before the main installer started.

Comment: I could just run setup.exe /s but that would require the customer to type it.  I assumed they would just want to double click the EXE.

Comment: I guess I read his question as: I want the user to get .net 45 automatically when they run my setup. So if he edits the PRQ he is using to install .net45 to always pass "/q /norestart", (and obviously have it properly detect if .net45 is already there) then whatever user installs his product (by running though it naturally) they will get .net45 before his setup is run; and thus without asking them if they want it.